# Getting sizeof a member of the class in C++

Tags: c++, class, sizeof

I've built a class called IntSet. My problem is that i dont want to storage another element that is the maximum amount of elements i want to introduce in `elem` array. So, in add method or any other method, i want to find out the max size i've allocated in the `IntSet (int dim_max)` constructor using this operation :

```
int n = sizeof(elem) / sizeof(*elem); //or sizeof(elem) / sizeof(int);
cout << "N is = " << n;
```

However, this doesnt work, everytime n is 1, even if i allocate  `elem = new int[dim_max];`, where dim_max is a variable i read from the keyboard and it's much bigger than 1. Here is the code :

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class IntSet{
    int *elem;
    int dim;

    public:

    IntSet (int dim_max) {
        dim = -1;
        elem = new int[dim_max];
    }

     void add(int new_el) {
        int n = sizeof(elem) / sizeof(int);
        cout << "N is =" << n;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(elem[i] == new_el) {
                cout << "It's already there !";
                return;
            }
        }
        dim++;
        if(dim == n) {
            elem = (int*)realloc(elem, sizeof(int) * (n + 1));
            global_var++;
        }
        elem[dim] = new_el;
     }
};
```

Comment: `elem` is a pointer to type int and `*elem` is an int type. It's always giving `1` because `sizeof(elem) == sizeof(int)` on your system. I'm assuming `dim` keeps track of the number of elements allocated to `elem` but you forgot to reassign `dim = dim_max` in the constructor and hence you don't have to calculate `n` since you already have the number of elements stored in `dim`.

Comment: Sizeof is evaluated at compile time so doesn't know about dynamic allocations

Comment: The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to. If you want "dynamic arrays" use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. Or if this is an assignment or exercise where you must use pointers and `new[]`, then keep track of the number of elements yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Comment: I understand now what i've done wrong. Thanks a lot. So i have to use another value to storage the max length of this array. And yes, 
I forgot to tell you, `dim` keeps track of how many elements i've got in that array after every 'add' method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator works on the types at compile time.  Since `elem` is an `int*`,  `sizeof(elem)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`.  And `*elem` is an `int`, so `sizeof(*elem)` is `sizeof(int)`.

So in the end, your formula is equivalent to `sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)`, regardless of what you put in `elem`.  There is no standard way to find out the number of elements of the array that that was allocated for a pointer.

For your purpose, you either must either keep track of `dim_max` in your class, or, better, replace the use of pointers and arrays with the nicer [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Vectors offer a [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) function, and allow to easily add new element dynamically at the end using [`push_back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back). Maybe it could interest you as well:  there is also a [`set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) container in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

`elem` is a pointer and `sizeof(ptr)` is always fixed. On 32-bit machine sizeof pointer is 32 bits ( 4 bytes), while on 64 bit machine it's 8 byte. Regardless of what data type they are pointing to, they have fixed size.

So, the computation you are doing `sizeof(elem)/sizeof(*elem)` will always yield 1 as it's matching with `sizeof(int)`. This would work if `elem` is an array with predetermined size.
To keep track of current size, you need to have another variable.

Another thing is don't mix `new` and `realloc`. Always use `new` as you are using C++.

Answer (score 2):

It is because, `elem` is a pointer. So, every time you are doing `sizeof(elem)` or `sizeof(*elem);` will give you the size of data type & pointer respectively.

If you havent used dynamic allocation, then answer would be OK.

I would suggest you to use STL container or store max size as a data member.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first you divide two non double value so the result is not what you expect
12/8 is 1.

sizeof a pointer depending on the architecture is 8 or 4.

What you think is `sizeof` returning the size of array which is only the case for automatic arrays not dynamic ones.